# Is it necessary to put public and private subnet in different vpc for extra safety

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-vpc

Currently we put public accessible resources like ALB inside public subnet, application servers and data storages inside private subnet (different data storage, say RDS and Elasticache, have their own subnets). All the subnets are living inside a single VPC.

My question is, is it 1) possible; 2) necessary to split this VPC into 2 separate VPCs, one VPC contains only public subnet and another VPC with only private subnet, to gain extra safety?

By saying extra safety, it means the 2-vpc topology could achieve additional security benefits than the current single vpc topology.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to do that, unless you mess up your configuration and leave it insecure. Think about the threat assessment, what are you protecting against?